# Change PHP extensions from version

Tags: php, memcached

I do not know how or why, but when I restarted my computer, my 'memcached' extension did not work anymore. After looking into it I saw that the extension.so-files of my PHP installation were installed into a o-debug...2012 folder. When I run php -i in terminal, it says this:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/memcached.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/memcached.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

So, I guess I have the wrong version of this extension installed. Is there a way to fix this?